# Debugging current project in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Every time i wanna debug or run something, i have to right-click my project -> run/debug as -> then specify what project i want to debug or run and specify "main" class. Earlier i could just press run/debug in the toolbar and it would automatically choose the project or class i was working with.

Answer (score 0):

The default appears to be set for running last project.

In the menu area for Eclipse

```
Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching
```

Check

```
Launch the selected resource in the editor (select settings as applicable)
```